# Query Porting to Impala

Tags: sql, variables, hive, hiveql, impala

I am trying to understand the small snippet from Query which must be adapted by Impala.

```
Select
.
.

from ${ENV_PREFIX}private_datalap_storage_customer_v1 cus
lateral view explode(adresses) address as addr
where year = substr(${REF_DATE}, 1, 4)
and month = substr(${REF_DATE}, 5, 2)
```

Can someone please help to understand what's happening in`from` and `Where` ?

Also, I will appreciate if someone can explain Why I have the below error when Tryin to Run the Query on Impala

> ParseException line 35:20 cannot recognize input near ',' ''1'' ',' in
> function specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substr() receives string, start position and length in chars to extract from start position. `substr('2021-02-20', 1, 4)` should extract `2021`.

Most probable, the variable is not resolved and you get `substr(, 1, 4)` instead of for example `substr('2021-02-20', 1, 4)`.In Impala,  [variables](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_shell_running_commands.html) are in this form `${var:var_name}`, check how are you passing it and how is it getting resolved using `select '${var:var_name}'`

Also I do not know how are you passing variable in Hive but string literal should be quoted, if variable itself does not contain quotes, this `substr(${REF_DATE}, 1, 4)` gets resolved as `substr(2021-02-20, 1, 4)`, which is wrong, so double check do you need to put `${REF_DATE}` in quotes or it already contains quotes.